# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'1\n5\n'

Tags: python, tcp, real-time

I have a program in python that is connected via TCP-IP to a matlab program, where the python code is the client and its receiving numbers like:

```
1
2
5
6
7
etc..
```

(the numbers I receive are only: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) in a random order. The error I'm getting is: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'1\n5\n'. My code is:

```
# TCP connection
try:
    so = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error as err:
    print ("socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))

#default port for socket
port = 2000

# default time out
#so.settimeout(1000000)

try:
    host_ip = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
except socket.gaierror:
    # this means could not resolve the host
    print ("there was an error resolving the host")
    sys.exit()

# connecting to the server
so.connect((host_ip,port))

# MATLAB INFORMATION FOR OFFLINE EXPERIMENT
Nepoch = 10  #nr de epochs por trial
Nwords = 7   #nr de palavras (SIM, NAO, FOME, SEDE, URINAR, AR, POSICAO)
SeqTrain = [1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6] #sequencia offline de treino

# read the TCP sequence received
def sequencia():
    num = 0
    for i in range(0,999):
        s = so.recv(port) #+ b'\n' #since the sequence received is : 1\n 2\n 5\n etc
        i = int(s)
        #print(i)
        #feedbak offline (for the user to know which are the words)
        if (num in (0, Nepoch*Nwords+1, Nepoch*Nwords*2+2, Nepoch*Nwords*3+3, Nepoch*Nwords*4+4, Nepoch*Nwords*5+5,\
                    Nepoch*Nwords*6+6)):
            labels1[i-1].configure(foreground="white")
            root.update()
        elif (num in (Nepoch*Nwords*7+7, Nepoch*Nwords*8+8, Nepoch*Nwords*9+9, Nepoch*Nwords*10+10,\
                     Nepoch*Nwords*11+11, Nepoch*Nwords*12+12, Nepoch*Nwords*13+13)):
            labels2[i-1].configure(foreground="white")
            root.update()
        else:
            labels[i-1].configure(background="green",foreground="red")
            root.update()
            winsound.PlaySound(sounds[i-1], winsound.SND_FILENAME)
            labels[i-1].configure(background="gray",foreground="white")
            root.update()
        num = num + 1
```

The numbers that I'm receiving are generated at real time in the matlab program. The thing is when I simulate with standard values in matlab the python program works just fine, which leads me to believe that is something because of the real-time values generated in the matlab.

Also when I comment the part of #feedbak offline (for the user to know which are the words) until the end, the program receives the numbers and does the i = int (s) without any problem, only when i uncomment the rest it gives me the errors.
When I print the values that I'm receiving is like:b'1\n' b'7\n' b'4\n' b'2\n' b'6\n' b'3\n' b'1\n' b'5\n' (etc..) -> it never says it receives 2 values at the same time, like it does when i uncomment the rest of the program

The all python program that i posted, works for the first 2/3 numbers and then gives me the error, here is the traceback:

```
>>> 
 RESTART: C:\Users\meca\Desktop\Python_Exercises\seq_tcp_offline-TCP-CLIENT.py 
b'1\n'
b'7\n'
b'4\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\meca\Desktop\Python_Exercises\seq_tcp_offline-TCP-CLIENT.py", line 139, in <module>
    sequencia()
  File "C:\Users\meca\Desktop\Python_Exercises\seq_tcp_offline-TCP-CLIENT.py", line 44, in sequencia
    i = int(s)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'2\n6\n'
```

This is very strange to me, any of you have any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\n` is a newline character. `int()` is having trouble when there are multiple newline characters in the bytes object.

A single number followed by a newline character can be *converted*.

```
>>> b = b'1\n'
>>> int(b)
1
```

When you receive a *stream* of numbers separated by newline characters you need to split the bytes object on the whitespace before converting.

```
>>> b = b'1\n5\n'
>>> b.split()
[b'1', b'5']
>>> for c in b.split():
...     print(int(c))

1
5
>>>
```

or

```
>>> [int(n) for n in b.split()]
[1, 5]
>>>
```

Alternatively, you could try reading only 2 bytes on each iteration. Currently you are passing a value of `2000` to the buffsize parameter.

```
s = so.recv(2)
```

You would want to test this though to make sure you don't use data - I don't know how the socket handles data that piles up if you only read 2 bytes at a time.
.

Comment: hello, thank you very much for your answer, it worked! but now i have a huge delay between the matlab and the python program! do you know any way to fix this delay? since it is real time programs, it's really important the timings. many thanks

Comment: `...now i have a huge delay...` - I really can't evaluate that statement. It sounds like a separate question so you should post a new one, details will be important - like determining what the bottleneck is. - first you might want to search with `python socket slow`.